# openscad - brik with 2 different bases, where one is scaled 2

Tags: 3d, 2d, radix, openscad

Lets say I have 2 bases and I want to create brik with it, the h=10
Lets have first base be A
Lets have second base be

```
difference() {
        A;
        offset(r=-1) A;
    }
```

How to do it? Of course in openSCAD

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [hull](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#hull) command, which

> Displays the convex hull of child nodes.